# How can I make my list save even after the page is reloaded

Tags: html, json, http, comments, forum

this is my whole thing I just want my comments to help Please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Forum</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="pixel">
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="blackBox">
        <p class="white">| <a class="white" href="file:///home/chronos/u-885ea83f13a0b735b4185df5cf6edb6dafb04e43/MyFiles/HTML%20Final/index.html">Home</a> | <a class="white" href="file:///home/chronos/u-885ea83f13a0b735b4185df5cf6edb6dafb04e43/MyFiles/HTML%20Final/textboxPhase.html">Textbox Phase</a> | <a class="white" href="file:///home/chronos/u-885ea83f13a0b735b4185df5cf6edb6dafb04e43/MyFiles/HTML%20Final/breakoutPhase.html">Breakout Phase</a> | <a class="white" href="file:///home/chronos/u-885ea83f13a0b735b4185df5cf6edb6dafb04e43/MyFiles/HTML%20Final/goatPhase.html">Goat Cage Phase</a> | <a class="white" href="file:///home/chronos/u-885ea83f13a0b735b4185df5cf6edb6dafb04e43/MyFiles/HTML%20Final/forum.html">Forum</a> |</p>
      </div><br>
      <br>
      <h1>Welcome to The "There is no Game" Forum</h1>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Leave us a comment</h2>
        <form>
          <textarea id="" placeholder="Add Your Comment" value=" "></textarea>
          <div class="btn">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Comment"> <button id="clear">Clear</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="comments">
          <h2>Comments</h2>
          <div id="comment-box">
            <ul>
              <li>WELCOME</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">


        const field = document.querySelector('textarea');
      const backUp = field.getAttribute('placeholder')
      const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
      const clear = document.getElementById('clear')
      const submit = document.querySelector('#submit')
      // const comments = document.querySelector('#comment-box')
      const comments = document.getElementById('comment-box');

      // array to store the comments
      const comments_arr = [];

      // to generate html list based on comments array
      const display_comments = () => {
      let list = '<ul>';
      comments_arr.forEach(comment => {
      list += `<li>${comment}<\/li>`;
      })
      list += '<\/ul>';
      comments.innerHTML = list;
      }

      clear.onclick = function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      // reset the array
      comments_arr.length = 0;
      // re-genrate the comment html list
      display_comments();
      }

      submit.onclick = function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      const content = field.value;
      if(content.length > 0){ // if there is content
      // add the comment to the array
      comments_arr.push(content);
      // re-genrate the comment html list
      display_comments();
      // reset the textArea content
      field.value = '';
      }
      }
      </script><br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="as-console-wrapper">
        <div class="as-console"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html
```

I know this code works but every time I reload it the comments disappear and I want it to save and all the code is too complex for my new code brain to understand. This is for my website and it's a basic wiki on how to beat there is no game, the old one. I need to turn this into my professor and wanted to add something extra but I want it so if I publish this the comment section isn't just a stupid gimmick.

Comment: well, you need a database for that, mongoDB would work pretty well for you here.

Comment: Well I would but I’m using Carey on a Chromebook working from scratch

Comment: So, use an online db to connect to?